# iOS UIImagePickerController black screen on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm meeting another strange problem....

I allow users to take photo. To do that, I'm using UIImagePickerController.

With iPhone, it's working, but with iPad (iOS 8, I don't know for others versions), I have a black screen preview.

This is my code :

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil))
    return NO;

UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

[self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:NULL];

return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"photo taken");
}
```

So when the user click on the button, I've the view to take the photo which appears. But the screen is black, and when I click on the button to take the photo, there is nothing.... and didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo isn't called.

(I see more topics, but I don't found any solution for this problem.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you run UIKit operations on main thread. Check also if you app has permissions to use camera [in device settings].

Comment: Oh my god.... it was that, the permission was unchecked.... I don't understand why I have the view of the photo if the permission is denied. 

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

***This can also be an issue.(If it helps someone.)***

Try this its solved my problem, make sure that there is a value

(Application name as string) in your `info.plist` > "**Bundle display name**".

In my case it was empty and because of that it didn't work.

If "**Bundle display name**" is not there in the info.plist,then add a row named "Bundle display name" and paste your appname .